# How to find extreme values of an $f(x,y)$ function?

Tags: extreme-value-theorem, extreme-value-analysis

I need this for my semester exams, unfortunately I was absent the day this topic was "talked about".

My function is the real-valued $$f(x,y)=x-xy+x^2+y^2$$, interpreted on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Single-valued functions could be handled easily by derivations, but what to do with two variables?

Comment: You need to associate a domain with your problem.  Is your domain finite, or is it all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, for example?

Comment: If it positive definite? Does it have extreme values?

Comment: The most obvious choice is $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hint: It is positive definite...

Comment: Hint: $f(x,y)+\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\left((x+1)^2+(x-y)^2+y^2\right)$

Comment: If domain is $\mathbb{R}^2$, then there is no maximum value. For example, take $x=0$ and vary $y$. Minimum can still be obtained (see my hint above).

Comment: We have a rule here, what I don't really agree, but the essence is that from the question should be visible, exactly what you know already. It is important even if it is obvious from your question. To avoid the closure of question, I inserted these informations in it. Feel free to rollback, if I estimated your current skills falsely.

Comment: You could also fix $y$ and find a solution with respect to $x$ and the repeat with $y$ as the variable.

Comment: @AnuragA Pretty good answer, in my opinion.

Comment: @peterh Thanks!

Comment: @AnuragA Thanks for your hint sir but can you explain it little bit further? Preferably by writing it down as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the extrems of a function of two (or more) variables, you need:

1. Look for the critical points, that is, points for which $\nabla f(x,y)=(0,0)$.

In your case, $\nabla f(x,y)=(1-y+2x,-x+2y)=(0,0) \iff x=-2/3,\ y=-1/3$.

2. Determine if the critical poitn is a maximum, minimum or saddle point, for example, you can find the Hessian matrix and look whether it is positive definite, negative definite or indefinite.

In your case, $H(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}2&-1\cr -1&2\end{pmatrix}$.

$Det(H(1,1))=5>0$ and $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}(1,1)=2>0$, so it is definite positive and you get a minimum.